# How to disable interpolated string angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-template, string-interpolation

I have following code line in my angular 7 template

```
<span>{{process.env.CLIENT_ID}}</span>
```

I want to disable interpolation on `{{process.env.CLIENT_ID}}` expiration so that it should render following text in browser.

> {{process.env.CLIENT_ID}}

***Is it possible to achieve this with out storing it into a variable as a string?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ngNonBindable` when we want tell Angular not to compile, or bind, a particular section of page.

```
<div ngNonBindable>
  {{process.env.CLIENT_ID}}
</div>
```

PS: I am not sure if this is official way as there is no documentation for it on the angular docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<span [innerHTML]="'\{\{process.env.CLIENT_ID\}\}'"></span>
```

Comment: Found it useful (+1) but, I think i should use ngNonBindable as suggested by @alt255

Comment: Sure, My idea was ngNonBindable  works with AngularJS only. I was wrong  :)